# How to send a one-off value using open-telemetry?

Tags: open-telemetry, telemetry

At startup, I'd like to send the count of outstanding operations a server process fetched from a DB. I think this should be a gauge value, since it's not really a counter, but in opentelemetry-js [there is only an “observable gauge”](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/9589d541cef7c8d0227d66c0c4fc2ee32ac93dbe/api/src/metrics/Meter.ts#L102) with a callback, which will end up reporting `foo.ops_at_startup: 87` for every metrics collection, which is completely unnecessary. Is there a way to only report a value once and then stop reporting this value?

Comment: Idk about opentelemetry-js, but in the python-sdk there is the unofficial possibility to set the metric reader interval to infinity, which leads to no signals being sent at all, and then manually call exporter.collect() - here's some hacky code I just wrote that shows how it works: https://github.com/datacontract/cli/compare/main...DGuhr:cli:otel_integration_hack